# Orleans direct client in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: orleans

I am currently looking into Orleans as a backend for Asp.net core web api project, and was wondering if anyone has any experience with its new feature - "direct client".  The orleans docs say "*it allows co-hosting a client and silo in a way that let the client communicate more efficiently with not just the silo it's attached to, but the entire cluster*", and I am aware that you can code something like this (and it works just fine in a console app):

```
var silo = new SiloHostBuilder()
               .UseLocalhostClustering()
               .EnableDirectClient()
               .Build();

await silo.StartAsync();

var client = silo.Services.GetRequiredService<IClusterClient>();
```

I am struggling trying to figure out where to put this type of code in an asp.net project that has its own webhost builder in "Main" (should it go to Startup class in "ConfigureServices"?).  In the end, we are aiming for a separate client/server setup, but for faster development it would be useful to play with a simple setup, which direct client appears to allow for. Any pointers to resources and/or sample solutions containing direct client with asp.net core would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**EDIT**: Here's the code that kinda works for me now, but I am not happy with he way the DI is set up

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            var silo = new SiloHostBuilder()
                    .UseLocalhostClustering()
                    .ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.AddDbContext<UserDbSet>(o =>  o.UseSqlite("Data Source=UserTest.db"));
                        services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
                    })
                    .EnableDirectClient()
                    .Build();

            await silo.StartAsync();

            var client = silo.Services.GetRequiredService<IClusterClient>();

            await WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                        .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .AddCommandLine(args)
                            .Build())
                        .ConfigureServices(services =>
                            services
                             .AddSingleton<IGrainFactory>(client)
                             .AddSingleton<IClusterClient>(client))
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .Build()
                        .RunAsync();
        }
```

If I put registration of the `DbContext` and `Mediatr` in the `StartUp` class, grain code fails with an exception indicating failure to instantiate the required dependencies.  Maybe I am doing something wrong when setting up the `Webhost`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For ASP.NET 2.x & Orleans below 2.3, I recommend creating & starting the silo before the Web host. When configuring the Web host, inject the `IGrainFactory` & `IClusterClient` instances from the silo (obtained via `silo.Services`):

```cs
var silo = new SiloHostBuilder()
    .UseLocalhostClustering()
    .EnableDirectClient()
    .Build();

await silo.StartAsync();

var client = silo.Services.GetRequiredService<IClusterClient>();

var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
        services
            .AddSingleton<IGrainFactory>(client)
            .AddSingleton<IClusterClient>(client))
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    // Other ASP.NET configuration...
    .Build();
```

For ASP.NET 3.0 & Orleans 2.3 or greater, the integration code becomes simpler due to the addition of `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` support in both frameworks:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureWebHost(builder =>
    {
        // Adding IGrainFactory, etc, is not necessary, since Orleans 
        // and ASP.NET share the same dependency injection container.
        builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .UseOrleans(builder =>
    {
        // EnableDirectClient is no longer needed as it is enabled by default
        builder.UseLocalhostClustering();
    })
    .Build();

await host.StartAsync();
```

Comment: Quick question - in the first example we use `ConfigureServices` extention to register `IGrainFactory` and `IClusterClient`.  The `Startup` class has its own `ConfigureServices` method, where the majority of container configuration is happening for an ASP code.  I assume they would be additive (i.e. not conflict with each other)?

Comment: They are additive. The startup class is static, so I cannot pass any state to it.

Comment: Hmm, if I try to add application's `DbContext` to ether the `StratUp` class or directly to `ConfigureServices` on the `WebHostBulder`, I end up getting
 `Unable to create an object of type 'UserDbSet'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728` message in the PMC.  Before adding the code for silo with direct client the application has no problems creating migrations and/or updating the database.  Any idea what could be the issue?

Example: `services.AddDbContext<UserDbSet>(o => o.UseSqlite("Data Source=User.db")) `

Comment: update: I was able to resolve this particular issue by adding `DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` class to my solution

Comment: update2: besides, I had to configure my `DbContext` in `SiloBuilder`, rather than in `StartUp` class, otherwise grain activation failed if I tried to inject `DbContext` in grain code. Appears that silo and webhost do not share the same service container.

Comment: SiloBuilder and WebHost ought to share the same container. It's a little more complicated with ASP.NET Core pre-3.0, though, since Startup class has a separate container (one container is used to build startup class and inject some core services)

Comment: Well, I use the code as above, and the container does not seem to be shared.  Is there an additional step I need to configure to make them use same?  I am pretty new to this "two hosts" paradigm.  Maybe in ASP.NET 3.0 & Orleans 2.3 this will be not an issue with single generic host.

Comment: I could not find any `UseStartup<StartUp>` extention on silo builder, and docs on Orleans are quite old on DI (only found some explanation on 1.5 docs section).

Comment: edited the original question to show the code I actually use, maybe something in it will ring the bell re incorrect DI setup.

Comment: Without the generic HostBuilder there will certainly be two containers - it cannot be avoided until HostBuilder is used